# Can't deploy Tesseract to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tesseract, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

I am working on an OCR using Tesseract. When I work local it works fine, but I can't make it work when I deploy to Google App Engine.

This is the line where the code breaks in the deploy:

```
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
```

I get this error from the *gcloud app logs tail -s*

> File "/app/pol_flow.py", line 1587, in upload_ocr      d =
>   pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py",
>   line 409, in image_to_data      if get_tesseract_version() < '3.05':
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py",
>   line 118, in wrapper      wrapper._result = func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py",
>   line 327, in get_tesseract_version      raise TesseractNotFoundError()
>   pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: /app is not installed
>   or it's not in your path
>
> TesseractNotFoundError()  pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: /app is not installed> or it's not in your path

I know that I have to pass the location into the code like this:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
```

But I don't know the path where Tesseract is installed when I make the deploy.

Thanks for your help!

PS: I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869385/can-not-make-tesseract-work-in-google-app-engine-with-python3/58302467#58302467) but when I make the request to the deployed endpoint in App Engine I still get the same error: TesseractNotFoundError()

Comment: Hi, Could you please share the command that you are using? gcloud app deploy? And if you could add the flag '--verbosity=debug', and paste the result, please?

Comment: Hi @BraulioBaron there I updated the question with the error from the log.
The deploy works fine, the problem is when I make the request to the endpoint because Tesseract can't find where it is installed.

Comment: @BraulioBaron *gcloud app deploy pol-app.yaml --verbosity=debug*

Comment: Hi Ari, the Tesseract library requires platform packages that don't come with the App Engine Standard Python3 runtime. As a workaround you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302467/7757976) to deploy your app in Cloud Run.

Comment: @llompalles I followed that answer but I still get the error when I deploy: 'TesseractNotFoundError()  pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: /app is not installed or it's not in your path'

Comment: @llompalles When I run my code local it works fine, but I need to specify this route: pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

How do I manage to do that in the deploy? Because I think that I am installing Tesseract correctly but App Engine can't find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the proper answer to your question would be that is not possible to do this with App Engine Standard. You can achieve this with App Engine Flexible environment: you can opt for a [Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build)  with a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) that allows you to install everything you need, in this case, Tesseract simply by adding `apt-get install tesseract-ocr`.

The other option would be to use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/), just as suggested by @llompalles. I have implemented [the solution he shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302467/7757976) and it works for me.