# Deploy flask paddleocr to Google Cloud Run error

Tags: flask, google-cloud-run, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

Anybody have experience deploy a flask paddleocr app to google cloud run?

I encounter Service Unavailable  when opening the url. In cloud run console: "ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

COPY . ./

RUN pip install flask gunicorn
RUN pip install paddlepaddle==2.4.2
RUN pip install paddleocr
RUN pip install pillow
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app
```

so far i have tried adding to Dockerfile

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl`

and

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl1.1`

but still get the same error in google cloud run

Any input will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: By any chance are you building the image locally on an ARM machine? Cloud Run requires x86 images, so if you're building on ARM, you'll need to specify the platform or you can use Cloud Build.

Comment: not trying on local machine yet. trying to get on google cloud. many of my projects are there

Comment: How are you building and deploying the container?

Comment: I am using this guide 
https://clincher.medium.com/deploy-a-simple-flask-application-in-google-cloud-run-bc0c644a31d5

i have deploy flask pytesseract using this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869385/can-not-make-tesseract-work-in-google-app-engine-with-python3
and its was successful. trying to replicate for paddleocr